# Question about differential forms

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I'm trying to learn about differential forms on my own, so i'm struggling with this problem:

Let $U⊂R$ be a open set, $F$ a vector-field and $f$ a function on $U$,
$dV := dx∧dy∧dz$ standard form of volume, $<.,.>$ and $(.,.,.)$ euclidean scalar and mixed product. Let us define forms: 
$η^1_F := <F, ·>$, $η^2_F := (F, ·, ·)$, $η^3_f:= f dV$.

Prove that:
1) $η^1_F∧η^1_G=η^2_{F×G}$,

2) $η^1_F∧η^2_G=η^3_{<F,G>}$,

3) $ω^3_{∇·F×G}=ω^3_{G·∇×F−F·∇×G}$.

I think, I proved the first one: $η^1_F∧η^1_G(\alpha,\beta)=<F,\alpha><G,\beta>-<F,\beta><G,\alpha>=<F\times G\times\alpha>\cdot\beta=(F\times G,\alpha,\beta)=η^2_{F×G}(\alpha,\beta)$.

I don't know how to prove 2. and 3.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can prove it all directly via coordinates. Fix a basis.

Comment: @ Canis Lupus This is probably elementary, but I still didn't managed to prove it. Could you please write down your solution?